# Materialize CSS wave effect doesn't work properly on Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, material-design, materialize

I have implemented Materialize CSS effect on my Application like

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large" href="#">Wave</a>
```

It is working properly on both Mobile and Desktops.

Only problem on mobile device is it triggers on touch. As per my requirement it should trigger on tap or click. not on touch.

Same problem is present here on their main site http://materializecss.com/

Is there any solution for this? Not able to find any. Need Help!

Comment: What's the difference between tap and touch in this scenario?

Comment: Why does it make any difference?
You will need a touchstart eventListener if you want it triggered by touchstart.

Comment: It's an open source project, you could try to [contribute](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#contributing) what you want. Now I can't see a way to do it in the source code.

Comment: @eskimo difference here is. on mobile if i scroll up while touching to waved tab. it starts giving those effects everywhere. Just need to know is there any way to differentiate scroll up and touch start case

Comment: @Rohit ah Ok got it. You best bet is to open a new issue on the [projects  github](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize). In [waves.js](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/7e0c265808cb8d6d27cba6555fa081ef94ff86b3/js/waves.js) around line 220 is the code for handling touch events, you cold try play around with that (maybe remove the touchstart event). I'll have a look this afternoon

Comment: @eskimo Yeah! exact same thing I tried already. not able to get tap event in base javascript to replace that existing code so every time touchstart is executed and just for tap event not willing to use entire JQuery/JQMobile. and raised issue #2701..no response over there so far